# PyCharm right-click on folder -> context menu: how to change from "hold down" to "toggle"?

Tags: python, pycharm

The latest oddity with this IDE is the default behaviour of right-clicking on a folder: it requires one to hold down the mouse button to navigate the menu, with selection occurring upon release.

Does anyone know how to change this setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Linux and using Eclipse keymap, [check this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-66182) for a workaround.